# HighChart exporting from IFrame

Tags: highcharts, export

I am displaying HighChart in a page and showing this page in a Iframe.

But I am unable to export the chart from the page which has iframe.
If I open the highchart page seperately,  I am able to export the chart.

What is the issuue?
I tried so many searchs

Answer (score 0):

May see this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/WxcE6/4/)

**EDIT:**

In the html page linked with the `iframe`, make sure you have something like this-

i.e. For the `index2.html` , check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/zdnzL/)

Comment: Yes. I added this script in the iframe page and also the page in which Iframe placed. the same example which is working in Fiddle is not working when I put the same page in iframe SRC

Comment: index.htm

<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-utf-8" />
  <title>Highcharts Examples</title>
         <script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>           
        
        <script type='text/javascript' src="js/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script  type='text/javascript' src="js/modules/exporting.js"></script>
       
 </head>
 <body>

      <div >
                <iframe style="width:1000px;height:300px" src="index2.htm"></iframe>
        </div>
           
 </body>
</html>

Comment: I did some modifications in ur fiddle- may like to see at-  http://jsfiddle.net/ishankdubey/zdnzL/

Comment: hi 
Thanks

But the actual problem is with the IE and Iframe. I am able to export the chart when I open Index.htm in FireFox. I am able to export the chart from index2.htm in IE. But we I try to export it from index.htm in IE 9 it is not working. I just found the security warrning of IE 9 it is saying that cross domain scripting block. this is due to http:\\export.highcharts.com.

Comment: If you are working behind https you need to setup your own exporting server. Simple jsFiddle examples works fine with exporting.